# Tomcat crashes while using unixDomainSocket as a connector

Tags: java, tomcat, unix-socket, apr

I was excited to see Tomcat 9 finally get support for Unix domain sockets, but it appears my setup is bad or incomplete.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a working example of a server.xml *anywhere* on the internet. What seems to be happening is that a unix domain socket doesn't have a remote IP, and Tomcat uses that in several places of it's stack.

When I kick off a curl request to the socket, the **second** request crashes and freezes the server up.

```
sudo curl  -kv -H "Connection: close" -H "x-forwarded-for: 127.0.0.1" http://localhost/hawtio/auth/login --unix-socket /opt/app-name/http.sock
```

I get a crash in the Tomcat log:

```
#first request
SEVERE [http-apr-/opt/app-name/http.sock-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
#011java.lang.NullPointerException
#011#011at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1770)
#011#011at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
#011#011at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
#011#011at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1133)
#011#011at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:624)
#011#011at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
#011#011at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
#011#011at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
#011#011at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
#011#011at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2113)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
#011#011at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

# second request
SEVERE [http-apr-/opt/app-name/http.sock-Acceptor] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error allocating socket processor
#011java.lang.NullPointerException
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.setSocketOptions(AprEndpoint.java:820)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.setSocketOptions(AprEndpoint.java:87)
#011#011at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:149)
#011#011at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Tomcat 9.0.64
- Java 11 Latest
- Apache Portable Runtime / Tomcat Native 1.2.35

Config:

```
    <Service name="CatalinaLocal">
        <Connector
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
            unixDomainSocketPath="/opt/app-name/http.sock" />
        <Engine
            defaultHost="localhost"
            name="Catalina">
            <Host
                name="localhost"
                appBase="webapps"
                unpackWARs="true"
                autoDeploy="false"
                deployIgnore="(?!.*hawtio).*">
                <Valve
                    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
```

If you take out the RemoteIpValve, same behavior.

## EDIT

The relevent code is here:
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.x/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AprEndpoint.java#L807

```
            // Do the duplicate accept check here rather than in serverSocketaccept()
            // so we can cache the results in the SocketWrapper
            AprSocketWrapper wrapper = new AprSocketWrapper(socket, this);
            // Bug does not affect Windows. Skip the check on that platform.
            if (!JrePlatform.IS_WINDOWS) {
                long currentNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
                if (wrapper.getRemotePort() == previousAcceptedPort) {
                    if (wrapper.getRemoteAddr().equals(previousAcceptedAddress)) {
                        if (currentNanoTime - previousAcceptedSocketNanoTime < 1000) {
                            throw new IOException(sm.getString("endpoint.err.duplicateAccept"));
                        }
                    }
                }
                previousAcceptedPort = wrapper.getRemotePort();
                previousAcceptedAddress = wrapper.getRemoteAddr();
                previousAcceptedSocketNanoTime = currentNanoTime;
            }
```

This is a bit interesting because this code is only present specifically in the AprEndpoint connector (That is Apache Portable Runtime, or invoking the Apache Server via JNI (Java Native Interface)), but I was unable to find the bug it is referencing that it is trying to fix. It may not be relevant to using the APR directly and this could be an oversight.

Comment: Looks like a problem in "somebody else's software" that you use - e.g. this might be good for serverfault, superuser, or even the Tomcat user or dev list. As it's not a problem with your code, I consider this question off-topic for stackoverflow - you're not looking to solve a programming problem ([help/on-topic])

Comment: I do not agree with that assumption. This very much is a programming question as it directly involves java code I'm invoking. And please don't remove the Apache Tag. To get this to work, you must have the Apache Portable Runtime installed as a library.

Comment: The [tag:apache] tag is for the Apache httpd server, not for the APR (please read the description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also experiencing the issue.... I started a conversation with the Tomcat devs, they agreed this was a bug, and A PR opened for Tomcat with a fix. Not released yet, but hopefully soon.

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/pull/532